# How to enable PeerJS connection and share data

Tags: javascript, html, peerjs

I am trying to build a peerjs connection and establish a chat between connections.

I am able to get connection ids however my code neither establishes the connection nor sends some text between devices.

Help me on the correct way to connect peers.

```js
let peer = new Peer();
let peerConnection;

// Generate Peer ID
peer.on('open', function (id) {
  div.innerHTML = `My peer ID is:  ${id}`;
});

// Function to connect with other Peer
function connect() {
  const idClient = document.getElementById("id").value;
  peerConnection = peer.connect(idClient);

  // On open will be launched when you successfully connect to
  peerConnection.on('open', function () {
    // Here you have conn.id
    peerConnection.send("hi!");
  });
}

// Receive message from other Peer
peer.on('connection', function (peerConnection) {
  peerConnection.on('data', function (data) {
    alert(data);
    // Will print "hi!"
  });
});


// Function to send message
function send() {
  if (!peerConnection.open) {
    alert("Peer connection is not open.");
    return;
  }
  const msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
  peerConnection.send(msg);
}

// Function to disconnect from the other peer
function disconnect() {
  peerConnection.close();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Messaging System</title>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.5.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div"></div>
 <input id="id" placeholder="Peer ID" />
 <button onclick="connect()">Connect</button>
 <textarea id="msg" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
 <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
 <button onclick="disconnect()">Disconnect</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooh! The code really works smoothly. I was initially using `alert()` to display the message however that wasn't showing up. I have updated my code by replacing `alert()` with `console.log()` which is now working.

```js
let peer = new Peer();
let peerConnection;

// Generate Peer ID
peer.on('open', function (id) {
  div.innerHTML = `My peer ID is:  ${id}`;
});

// Function to connect with other Peer
function connect() {
  const idClient = document.getElementById("id").value;
  peerConnection = peer.connect(idClient);

  // On open will be launched when you successfully connect to
  peerConnection.on('open', function () {
    // Here you have conn.id
    peerConnection.send("hi!");
  });
}

// Receive message from other Peer
peer.on('connection', function (peerConnection) {
  peerConnection.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    // Will print "hi!"
  });
});


// Function to send message
function send() {
  if (!peerConnection.open) {
    console.log("Peer connection is not open.");
    return;
  }
  const msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
  peerConnection.send(msg);
}

// Function to disconnect from the other peer
function disconnect() {
  peerConnection.close();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Messaging System</title>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.5.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div"></div>
 <input id="id" placeholder="Peer ID" />
 <button onclick="connect()">Connect</button>
 <textarea id="msg" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
 <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
 <button onclick="disconnect()">Disconnect</button>
</body>
```